# Docker links with awsvpc network mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a Java webapp deployed in ECS using the tomcat:8.5-jre8-alpine image. The network mode for this task is awsvpc; I have many of these tasks running across 3 EC2 instances fronted by an ALB.

This is working fine but now I want to add an nginx reverse-proxy in front of each tomcat container, similar to this example: https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-nginx-reverse-proxy/tree/master/reverse-proxy.

My abbreviated container definition file is:

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
     {
       "name": "nginx",
       "image": "<NGINX reverse proxy image URL>",
       "memory": "256",
       "cpu": "256",
       "essential": true,
       "portMappings": [
         {
           "containerPort": "80",
           "protocol": "tcp"
         }
       ],
       "links": [
         "app"
       ]
     },
     {
       "name": "app",
       "image": "<app image URL>",
       "memory": "1024",
       "cpu": "1024",
       "essential": true
     }
    ],
    "volumes": [],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "family": "application-stack"
}
```

When I try to save a new task definition I received the error: "links are not supported when the network type is awsvpc"

I am using the awsvpc network mode because it gives me granular control over the inbound traffic via a security group.

Is there any way to create a task definition with 2 linked containers when using awsvpc network mode?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You dont need the linking part at all, because awsvpc allows you to reference other containers simply by using

```
localhost:8080
```

(or whatever port is your other container mapped to)
in your nginx config file.

So remove links from your json and use `localhost:{container port}` in nginx config. Simple as that.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me to use the same hostname for multiple containers. There should be an option to provide extra hostnames.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you want to use a reverse-proxy you can stop using links, because you can make service discovery or using your reverse-proxy to use your dependency.

If you still want to use `link` instead of using that reverse proxy you can use [consul](https://www.consul.io/) and [Fabio](https://github.com/fabiolb/fabio). Both services are dockerizable.

With this, there is no necessity to use awsvpc and you can use consul for service-discovery.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input; in my scenario I want to use awsvpc because I can associate a security group to the ENI. I want to expose the nginx container but not the tomcat container, and I want the nginx container to be able to communicate with the tomcat container. Is this possible when using networkMode: awsvpc?

Comment: Hmmm I've never had the chance to user awsvpc, but you can do this:
Using a private subnet and a public, public subnet will have nginx for example, and the other one your tomcat. Create a security group for making your network visible between your instances, and create a ALB and expose your nginx through them. With some tweaks in your R53 with private hosted zones and public hosted zone you can resolve that.