# error ClientException: Links are not supported when networkMode=awsvpc in fargate terraform

Tags: node.js, nginx, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I got an error in terraform:

> ```
> ClientException: Links are not supported when networkMode=awsvpc.
> ```

I link nginx with my nodejs application. I want nodejs to run on 3000 port, and nginx run on 80 and when the request is incoming then nginx will do proxy to nodejs. ( I have defined nginx.conf with proxy to 3000).

Its happens in fargate mode. but I don't have choice here, the network mode is only a `awsvpc`.

What I can do? there is a way to link between the containers? one conatiner, nginx and nodejs inside? just nodejs? other solution?

here my terraform settings:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "nginx" {
  name            = "nginx-${var.app}"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.demo.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.nginx.arn
  desired_count   = 4
  launch_type = "FARGATE"

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [task_definition]
  }
 ...
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "nginx" {
  family = "nginx-${var.app}"

  container_definitions = file("container_definitions.json")

  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
}
```

container_definitions.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "nginx-...nginx-www",
    "image": "311443.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/...-nginx:latest",
    "cpu": 256,
    "memory": 256,
    "essential": true,
    "links": ["www-app"],
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": 80
      }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "...",
        "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "www-app",
    "image": "93934.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/..../www-app:latest",
    "cpu": 256,
    "memory": 256,
    "essential": true,
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "/ecs-..../nginx",
        "awslogs-region": "us-east-2",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I think this is an error coming from the remote ECS API rather than from Terraform, in which case the answers to this other question might help: [Docker links with awsvpc network mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772120/docker-links-with-awsvpc-network-mode)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

I recommend you link config file that is located s3 to ecs nginx.

---

Between ecs containers, each other is linked on same network. And AWS enforces network mode if you use fargates.

There are two ways solutions.

1. Configure nginx config for container nginx image.

just forward web port 80 to 3000 node port. Nginx is primarily designed that subject.

upload nginx.config file to s3 and then link that s3 arn to ecs with "EnvironmentFile" field.

Or you can build own nginx image with custom config (not recommended).

2. just give up using nginx. Web port can be forward with application load balancer.

you can forward from 80 to 3000 on Application Load Balancer. It is depends on your app size. If that is simple app, You have not to use nginx.

Normally Nginx is used as reverse proxy, but can be used control http buffering(proxy buffer), graceful restart, queueing request etc..